# Do we have a "Contains" method in IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have a class in my code that is already deriving from IEnumerable.
I was wondering if there is a way that I can use a "Contains" method on its instnaces to look for a something in that list?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do you *really* implement the non-generic `IEnumerable`, or the generic `IEnumerable<T>`? If you can possibly implement the generic one, your life will become a lot simpler - as then you can use [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), which does indeed have a [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) extension method.

Otherwise, you could potentially convert from the non-generic to generic using `Cast` or `OfType`, e.g.

```
bool found = nonGeneric.Cast<TargetType>().Contains(targetItem);
```

It would be nicer if you just implemented the generic interface to start with though :)

Answer (score 28):

No, there's no such method in the [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface. There's an [`extension method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) though that you could use.

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then:

```
IEnumerable<string> foos = new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
bool IsThereABar = foos.Contains("bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable source, T value)
    {
        foreach (var i in source)
        {
            if (Equals(i, value))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If you want, you can add custom comparer as parameter ti extension method Contains