# Check IEnumerable using Contains() in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to render a list of links, and the icon should change depending on wether the item Id is found within an `IEnumerable` or not.

This is the relevant part of my view so far:

```
@{
if (product.InFrontPages.Contains(item.ParentCategory.Id))
    {
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-checked"></span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
    }
}
```

This causes a compile time error:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains(ParallelQuery, int)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery'

I think I may want to implement [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767277/do-we-have-a-contains-method-in-ienumerable), but I haven't figured out how to do it. I don't understand what Jon means when he suggests implementing the generic interface.

The involved viewmodels:

```
public class ViewModelProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCategoryWithTitle> Categories { get; set; }
}

    public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string ProductCountInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return Products != null && Products.Any() ? Products.Count().ToString() : "0";
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<FrontPageProduct> FrontPageProducts { get; set; }
    public ViewModelProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills I added the involved viewmodels.

Comment: @mjwills I get an error on `.Count()?`: "Operator ? cannot be applied to operand of type int".

Comment: Use `return Products?.Count().ToString() ?? "0"`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `Contains` LINQ method doesn't have the signature you expect - you're trying to check whether an `IEnumerable<FrontPageProduct>` contains an `int`... it can't, because it only has `FrontPageProduct` references.

I suspect you want something like:

```
if (product.InFrontPages.Any(page => page.Id == item.ParentCategory.Id)
```

(I'd potentially use a conditional operator instead of an `if` statement, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be with a lamda expression. Something like this

```
@{
if (product.InFrontPages.Contains(c => c.ParentCategory.Id == item.ParentCategory.Id))
    {
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-checked"></span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
    }
}
```