# Casting an object into the same type as an IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#

In essence I have function which takes arguments : `ContainsValue(IEnumerable collection, object obj)`

And I need to check if collection `Contains` obj **with the use of Equals().**

Specifically collection is an array of strings and obj is a custom type/class (Its called FString, I dont completely understand what it is but it is at least somewhat derivative from string).

Unfortunately the solution needs to be generic so I cant explicitly reference the custom type.

And so I need a way to generically cast obj into whatever type the collection is.
Is this possible?

EDIT:

```
static bool ContainsValue(IEnumerable collection, object obj)
{
    // cast obj into same type as collection elements

    foreach(var element in collection)
    {
        if() // element equals obj
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we have a "Contains" method in IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767277/do-we-have-a-contains-method-in-ienumerable)

Comment: Does this edit clarify things? I just need to cast an object into the the type of the IEnumerable without knowing the target type until runtime

Comment: Why not use [`object.Equals(obj, element)`](http://rextester.com/UEOB19407)? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @John - "Cannot access static method 'Equals' in non-static context" Is the error that produces

Comment: Then why doesn't it produce that error on the fiddle I linked? Do you have your own type/variable called `object`?

Comment: Thanks john, you're right, had it typed wrong

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to use this in your `if` statement:

```
if(object.Equals(element, obj))
```

and then you don't need to cast at all, or worry about nulls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The details are quite vague but `Enumerable.Cast(IEnumerable) Method` may help.

Doco, with an example, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> ```
>  System.Collections.ArrayList fruits = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
>  fruits.Add("mango");
>  fruits.Add("apple");
>  fruits.Add("lemon");
>
>  IEnumerable<string> query =
>      fruits.Cast<string>().OrderBy(fruit => fruit).Select(fruit => fruit);
>
>  // The following code, without the cast, doesn't compile.
>  //IEnumerable<string> query1 =
>  //    fruits.OrderBy(fruit => fruit).Select(fruit => fruit);
>
>  foreach (string fruit in query)
>  {
>      Console.WriteLine(fruit);
>  }
>
>  // This code produces the following output: 
>  //
>  // apple 
>  // lemon
>  // mango
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this (if you can access fields of the collection):

```
string objAsString = obj?.ToString() ?? "";

if(collection.Any(x => x.field == objAsString))
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IEnumerable`'s [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to extract the target type you are looking for and if there are some check the equality situation you mentioned...such as this example

```
return collection.OfType<string>()
                 .Any( str => str.Equals("Jabberwocky"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> And so I need a way to generically cast obj into whatever type the collection is. Is this possible?

If that is your only question then the solution is easy. Please edit your question if you need something more than this.

```
static bool ContainsValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, object obj) where T : class
{
    var compareTo = obj as T;
    if (obj == null) return false;  //Return false if cast was not possible
    foreach (var item in collection) 
    {
        if (item == obj) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could also force the caller to do the cast, which seems like a smarter way to go about it, since then you can enforce type safety at compile time. Also you can shorten  the code with a tiny bit of LINQ.

```
static bool ContainsValue<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, T obj) where T : class
{
    return collection.Any( item => item == obj );
}
```